# Barcode and Qrcode scanning using Angular js HTML5

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs

I require to scan Barcode and Qrcode on Android /iphone/ipad devices.
The Project is completely based on Angular JS and HTML5.It is mobile website.

Below is the requirement.
It should not download any third party native application on device.So unable to use native Zxing application.

So,is there any way in javascript/HTML5/jquery/Angular js through which we can scan barcode using native camera?

We tried below javascript library but found not useful as it is only for QRcode and not opening camera as well.
https://github.com/LazarSoft

Please Help!!

Comment: Without Flash (or some yet unreleased improvement to the File API) there is simply no way to grab data from a mobile camera and process it client side in JavaScript (the LazerSoft library is impressive, but it gets the camera data from a Flash SWF, and converts it to a canvas element).  You could prompt a user to upload an image taken from their camera and have a server side block of code running. this would not come close to the performance or a native app.  Maybe something like PhoneGap or Titanium?

Comment: on Android and ios mobile browser for flash "This plugin is not supported error was coming".It is requirement by client that we should not open gallery.

Comment: Wondering if you found a solution as I am having the same issue

Comment: It's now 2017 and still there isn't a library I can find that will do barcodes and QR codes in javascript/angular/jquery

Comment: There is a built-in barcode scanner API in js now [you can read more about it here](https://www.jsnow.io/javascript/creating-a-real-time-qr-code-scanner-with-vanilla-javascript-part-1) so far not fully supported for all browsers but can scan barcodes and QR codes.

Answer (score 5):

Please read through this plugin, should help you achieve what you are looking for. Try the DEMO [LINK](http://dwa012.github.io/html5-qrcode/) - This is a cross platform jQuery library to create a QRcode reader for HTML5 compatible browser.

Comment: Hi thanks but I am unable to resolve the problem yet.I integrated this library,but it is not opening native camera on Android- chromer and native browser/iphone-safari browser. Blank screen is coming. Please suggest any library which can do following 1.open device camera 2. scan barcode and qr code and return back the same to Angular js application.

Comment: Below logs come on Android chrome browser.Native web camera streaming (getUserMedia) not supported in this browser. html5-qrcode.min.js:104

Comment: @user2425109 Try opening this one in your current Android chrome browser [link](http://shinydemos.com/qr-code/)

Comment: @user2425109 Check this post for Web RTC error (getUserMedia) not supported [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13383860/webrtc-getusermedia-not-showing-video) also see Getting Started Web RTC [link](http://www.netmagazine.com/tutorials/get-started-webrtc)

Comment: It is giving error "This plugin is not supported" in mobile browser as well.

Comment: how to make it use the rear camera not the front camera?

Answer (score 5):

I adapted html5-qrcode plugin as AngularJS directive.

You can find it in this repo:

https://github.com/sembrestels/angular-qr-scanner

Comment: Kindly explain your answer please.

Comment: Would be useful to be able to trigger the scanner to start, for example, when a user clicks a button, rather than having it start at page load. Otherwise very helpful demo.

Comment: Hey @Sem this directive is awesome! Thanks for this. Do you know if it's possible to integrate this in a Angular app embedded in Cordova/Phonegap? Anyway, I'm gonna try it.

Comment: This won't work on mobile devices since getUserMedia isn't supported there. It will work in modern desktop browsers like Chrome.

Comment: @David any news on your try?