# Barcode scanning using javascript OR Angular Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, html5-canvas

Can any one tell me how to do scanning using JavaScript OR AngularJS. Here is link i have gone through but it does not work.

[Barcode and Qrcode scanning using Angular js HTML5](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17939663/barcode-and-qrcode-scanning-using-angular-js-html5).

I want something like this-

1- On click of button in `html5` open the camera

2- Scan the Bar Code/Qr Code

3- Get the result.

Please let me know if any one knows about this.

Comment: I thought web browsers wouldn't let you access a camera.

Comment: that will be possible to open the camera.. but how to scan and get result?? Is there any library in javascript?

Comment: Check out this previous Stackoverflow answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10810277/javascript-library-for-qr-image-decoder

Comment: I adapted html5-qrcode plugin as AngularJS directive. Look at https://github.com/sembrestels/angular-qr-scanner

Comment: I have tried this 'https://github.com/sembrestels/angular-qr-scanner' but its not working as expected.